# NSXMLParser multithreading issue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, nsxmlparser

I am developing an iPad application with an UISplitViewController.

If a cell in the masterview is clicked, the detailView runs `NSXMLParsers` to load the needed data. To keep the UI usable, this is done in an extra thread.
The application uses different `detailViewControllers` that use different parsing classes implementing `NSXMLParserDelegate`.

My problem is that it seems like `NSXMLParser`'s `[parser parse]` method can only be run once, since if I try to run it in several threads at the same time I get an *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error.

Now, if the user selects a row in the masterView and then another row, while the first detailView is still loading and parsing the data, two threads try to use the parse method, which throws the error mentioned above.

So I am wondering how to achieve, that this method is only run once although it is used in different threads and different instances / classes.

Comment: Do you init NSXMLParser per thread?

Comment: the detailViewControllers initialize a class that responds to NSXMLParserDelegate. I need to parse different files, so I have several classes that act as delegates and initialize NSXMLParser.

Comment: the problem is that [[NSXMLParser alloc] init] gets called while another thread is using [xmlParser parse]. This causes the parse method to crash the app.So I'd need to know if NSXMLParser is allocated in the moment and wait until it is dealloced. Is there a way to check if an instance of NSXMLParser exists?